# Azure web site instances

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

How long does it take to spin up a new instance of a website on the azure platform?

So If I have 1 instance and I want to increase to say 3 - how long will it take for the other 2 instances to serve requests?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

With Azure Websites it is instant (few seconds) - under assumption there is incoming traffic to activate those instances. Azure Websites has already a pool of machines standing by, so the only thing you notice is a cold start of your site on a new machine.

Answer (score 0):

I just did this. It took just under 10 minutes. Although not instant, this seems reasonable for most scenarios, especially if you know that your site is about to be hit. What is important though, is that this answer is really only a guess. There are many variables that could affect this massively:

- I was using a smallish .Net web service - a larger app could be slower to deploy?
- My service runs on Windows Server 2012 - are other editions faster/slower?
- Do MS sometimes have new VMs on standby for quick deployment?
- I'm sure the Azure centres are busier/slower at certain times than others
- If you have a large/slow set of startup scripts, this will all add time

I don't know answers to any of those but hopefully this gives you an idea.

EDIT: Just to be clear - I did this on Cloud Services, not "Web Sites", which I don't have any of! I'm not always sure whether OPs know the difference - I used to call my Web Sites for ages!